# Excel VBA Code for language translation broken?

Tags: vba, excel

This code should translate all the words from it's dictionary in a cell, but instead, it translates only the first line (it only translates "E" to "And"), it should go through all the words and change all the words in the cell.

```
Sub traducaobeta2()

Dim translate As Object 'scritping.Dictionary

Set translate = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

translate("e") = "and"
translate("Telefones") = "Telephones"
translate("Livros") = "Books"
translate("Criado mudo") = "Night stand"
translate("Banqueta") = "Stool"
translate("livros") = "books"
translate("cadernos") = "papers"
translate("travesseiros") = "pillows"
translate("Mesa") = "Table"
translate("Materiais de escritório") = "Office materials"
' the list goes on...


Dim Words As Variant
Dim I As Integer
Words = Split(LCase(activecell.Value))


For I = LBound(Words) To UBound(Words)
    If translate(Words(I)) <> "" Then Words(I) = translate(Words(I))
Next
activecell.Value = Join(Words)
activecell.Value = Ucase$(Left$(activecell.Value, 1)) & Right$(activecell.Value, Len(activecell.Value) - 1)
end sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `Split()` like this it puts each word into the array but changes them to lower case. The keys in the dictionary are case sensitive and so you need to use lower case keys instead.

```
translate("e") = "and"
translate("telefones") = "Telephones"
translate("livros") = "Books"
translate("criado mudo") = "Night stand"
translate("banqueta") = "Stool"
translate("livros") = "books"
translate("cadernos") = "papers"
translate("travesseiros") = "pillows"
translate("mesa") = "Table"
translate("materiais de escritório") = "Office materials"
' the list goes on...
```

on a side note, that last one `("materiais de escritório")` will never work because it has spaces in so your array will have `materiais`, `de` and `escritório` in separate indexes and will never match the dictionary key.

Comment: That is true, they wont work. I will build a Case select for those words first, and then the split module will enter the scene

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Macro Man's excellent comments, another approach is to completely ignore the LCase, UCase issue.  Do not attempt to change or fix cases at all. Instead just beef-up the translate object like:

```
translate("livros") = "books"
translate("Livros") = "Books"
```

If the source text has proper capitalization, the translate will work and if the source text is all lower case, the translate should work.

Comment: An even better idea! +1

Comment: Thank you Gary and macro man!!  Do you also know how do I test the cell so I know if all the words were translated?

Comment: To remove the cases Would this be the correct approach?
Words = Split(activecell.Value)               ________________________________________________                                                                                                

activecell.Value = (Left$(activecell.Value, 1)) & Right$(activecell.Value, Len(activecell.Value) - 1)

Comment: @ADrex  I don't think you will need the last line of your original code....................its only purpose is to enforce Proper case.

Comment: Just removed and now they are going all to LowerCase, I wrote the words on different cases on the dictionary as you sugested, so it would be better if the code didnt change the cases